# fmt.Printf() flag '0' is not ignored for strings

Tags: go

According to the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#pkg-overview), the flag '0' is ignored for strings

> '0'   pad with leading zeros rather than spaces;
> for numbers, this moves the padding after the sign;
> ignored for strings, byte slices and byte arrays

but the flag '0' is not ignored in below code. Is the doc wrong? Or do I misunderstand it?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%05s", "abc")
    // print 00abc
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you found a bug.

[The source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/fmt/print.go;l=1037) resets the `zero` flag only for `-` (minus) flag. It is not modified neither for strings nor for any other type.

And the [function that outputs a string](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/fmt/format.go;l=108) doesn't reset the `zero` flag either.

Comment: Thank you for the source code check. [A github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56486) is submitted.